# Data transformations on-the-fly

Tags: apache-spark, mapping, apache-storm

Is there a way, other than a manual mapping, to translate related values on-the-fly? I know this sounds vague but what I am looking for is a way to take an input value of say "2015 Ford" and translate it given to a mapping provided by a client that indicates the same value in their system. Say they provide us with a mapping of how each car is represented in their system. So something like this:

"Ford" -> 1111
"BMW" -> 2222
"Ferrari" -> 5050

I would like to see if something like a storm bolt could be used to achieve this. (Obviously, I am not familiar with storm beyond it data enrichment capabilities) Or if there may be another data system that provides this. Because doing a one-off mapping for each of my clients does not really feel feasible.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want join your mapping file with the live stream(or batch data).

In spark you can broadcast your mapping file and then use it like hashmap to update your live stream.